# implemented simple facebook authentication in android but failed to create app in firbase

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

i have tried to create app in firebase but it shows this error:-
*A Firebase or Google Cloud project contains an OAuth 2.0 client ID (such as another registered Android app) that has the same package name and SHA-1 key that's listed for one of your Android apps in this project. Before you can download this config file, you'll need to resolve this issue.*

But i have never registered the project before

May be because i have done google authentication and facebook authentication and at that time already registered my project name and sigin key

Comment: Are you sure you haven't create a project with the same package name? or if you deleted the project then you need to wait for 3 to 5 working days

Comment: no I haven't created